# Avoid String charAt() method inside loops

Tags: java, string, for-loop

Is there any effect on Code Optimization(Speed etc) if i replace ?

// Before

```
public void test(String str)  
{
     for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
     {      
          System.out.println(str.charAt(i)); // VIOLATION 
     }
}
```

The above Code Snippet with below code :-

// After

```
public void test(String str)
{      
     char[] ch = str.toCharArray(); // CORRECTION
     for(int i=0; i < ch.length; i++) 
     {             
          System.out.println(ch[i]); // CORRECTION    
     }
}
```

Comment: Really the only way to answer "Is X faster than Y?" is to try it.

Comment: Optimizations are better done when you run into a bottleneck and pinpoint it to a specific bit of code. Did you discover that this bit of code is what causes your application to be slow?

Comment: `toCharArray` will have to iterate over entire String and create array which will be copy of all characters first. Then you will have to iterate over that copy again. `charAt` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @Pshemo :-) On the other hand, `System.out.println(ch[i]);` might run faster on some machines because it is direct access to array indices (The JIT might optimize it really well).. In case of `charAt()` there are addtional conditional checks each time it is called which might rpevent JIT from optimizing code. :)

Comment: Really small (and useless) optimisation :"premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @TheLostMind True, that is why generally we don't bother in optimization until we see that some functionality is really slow :) As already being said "[Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will see any *noticeable* difference. Even if you do, I believe it varies from platform to platform.

```
 for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
```

Will be changed by the compiler to something like:

```
int strLength = str.length();
 for(int i=0; i<strLength ; i++)
```

So, you will not be calculating the length each time inside the loop.

I think the second case will be *only slightly* faster (I could be wrong) because array access is faster and can easily be optimized by the compiler. `charAt()` in its byte-code form also accesses the same array but has additional instructions to check for `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` (2 conditional checks inside an `if`).

As *Pshemo* said -*toCharArray will have to iterate over entire String and create array which will be copy of all characters first. Then you will have to iterate over that copy again. charAt doesn't have this problem*.

So, on a whole, the answer might differ from architecture to architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Still you can optimized.

```
public void test(String str)
{      
     char[] ch = str.toCharArray(); // CORRECTION
     int n = ch.length;
     for(int i=0; i < n; i++) 
     {             
           System.out.println(ch[i]); // CORRECTION    
     }
}
```

Comment: Not the Down voter.. but the length of the array will be known during compile time.. The compiler will do the exact (or even better) correction than what you have already done.. This will not affect run-time performance

Comment: I can't agree, how exactly will it be known at compile time if the str is passed as an argument?